# session in php dando erro

Tags: php, sql, session

Boa tarde galera, to tentando desde ontem e nao to conseguindo, seguinte possuo essas duas tabelas no banco, quando eu logo ele salva essa sessao   $_SESSION['username'] = $username;

porem preciso dar um select nos pets cadastrados e eles retornam todo o conteudo do banco e nao as que o usuario cadastrou

```sql
CREATE TABLE `novo_pet` (
    `id_novopet_cod` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `nome_animal` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    `raca_animal` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    `idade_animal` INT(2) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `cor_animal` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    `especie_animal` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    `porte_animal` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    `sexo_animal` VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL,
    `proprietario_animal` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    `caracteristica_animal` VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL,
    `telefone_animal` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    `image` TEXT NOT NULL,
    `situacao_animal` TEXT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id_novopet_cod`)
)
COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'
ENGINE=MyISAM
AUTO_INCREMENT=4
;

CREATE TABLE `usuario` (
  `id_usuario_cod` int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `username` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `senha` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `telefone` varchar (12) not null,
   `sexo_usuario` varchar (10) not null,
  `trn_date` datetime NOT NULL
);
```

```php
?php
$sql = "select * from novo_pet  "; 
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
if(mysqli_num_rows($result)){
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
```

se alguem puder me ajudar nessa questao, desde ja agradeço as ajudas.                ?>

Comment: Bom  há varios pontos em seu  codigo  que precisam  ser melhorados,  1° como  você sabe quem  cadastrou  cada  pet   ? você precisa adicionar  uma foreign key  na sua tabela pets referenciando  ao  usuário. segundo  seu  select  não  tem  where, ou  seja você está trazendo  todos os dados do  banco

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primeiramente você precisa referenciar quem cadastrou o  pet, para isso  você precisa adicionar  uma foreign key  na sua tabela pets

```
ALTER TABLE novo_pet ADD id_usuario_cod_fk int not null
ALTER TABLE novo_pet ADD FOREIGN KEY(id_usuario_cod_fk) references usuario(id_usuario_cod)
```

Algora na sua Query altere-a do  seguinte modo

```
SELECT * FROM novo_pet 
JOIN usuario ON usuario.id_usuario_cod = novo_pet.id_usuario_cod_fk
where usuario.username = 'nomeDaSuaSessão'
```

Comment: o insert nao ta mais funcionando rsrrs, e to apanhando para tentar arrumar, agradeço muito pela sua resposta.

Comment: você provavelmente vai ter que informar  o  id_usuario_cod no  insert tanta salvar esse valor numa sessão  também

Comment: no insert direto feito no HeidiSQL funcionou, mas na página do site, dei um ecko pra ver o que aparece e onde eu coloquei 1 no sql ele me retorna ' teste' que e o nome do usuario e nao o codigo do usuario usei assim ´´´ $rn = $_SESSION['username'];´´mas como pego o username pra logar nao ta inserindo